# Binary string representation of a float returns 0

Tags: c#, .net

When I launch this console application I get `0`, instead of 32 bit string. It throws no error, however.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        double num = 2.75;

        byte [] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
        int toInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        string bitString = Convert.ToString(toInt);

        Console.WriteLine(bitString);
    }
```

Comment: try `Convert.ToString((int) num, 2)`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: That isn't what he wants.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yours prints out `10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double` is 64 bits.

You're looking at the top 32 bits, which are all zero.

You want `float` (or call `ToInt64` to see all of the bits).

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Also, I had to go with `long`, complains about `float`

Comment: change `int toInt` to `long toInt`... @SvetanDimoff

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Why is it, that when I try to use `float`  for `num` I get `Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float'; use an 'F' suffix to create a literal of this type`? How is `2.75` a `double` by definition, so I can't use `float`?

Comment: `2.75` is double. either write `2.75f` or cast like `(float)2.75` @SvetanDimoff